# The name of the packages for XFCE4 themes and icons in Ubuntu?

Tags: server, 22.04, icons, themes, xfce

I installed xfce4 without the "recommends" on Ubuntu Server 22.04LTS. In xfce -> preference -> appearance, style is empty, and selecting icons crashes the GUI. Also, a lot of system icons are missing. I do not want to install the whole xfce package, because I want minimal desktop.

What packages should I install to have at least some styles (including a dark theme) and some full icon sets?

Comment: There's a [`xubuntu-artwork`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xubuntu-artwork) meta package. Not sure whether it brings in a dark theme.

Comment: @muru Well, installing that installed 3 styles (including Greybird-dark) and a bunch of icon themes. I could set those styles/icons, but applying them still make the UI crash (by crash, I mean, the UI goes back to All Settings). I think this is good enough, but just out of curiosity, the `xfce4-goodies` package seems to contain `xfce4-artwork`, can't that be installed separately without installing the whole `xfce4-goodies`?